# c# Casting List<object> to List<?>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Currently I have an object of type `IList<object>` and I need to convert to another type of `IList` using Type object.

eg.

```
Type t = typeof(MyType);
var list = OtherClass.MyFunction(myParam param);
```

The ***var list*** is of type `IList<object>` and I need it to be of type `IList<t>`

Currently I have a static function and call for reflection, but this is called within a loop and need to minimize the maximum time spent in my loops.

Anyone know any other way to perform this conversion without using reflection?

With delegate maybe?

Comment: i believe that linq has a `Cast()` extension method

Comment: It's all using reflection under the hood.

Comment: You can't get the compile-time type if you're given the type at runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If T isn't known at compile time, I suppose you could:

```
var type = typeof(int);
IList<object> myList = (new object[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}).ToList();
var mi = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
var mRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type);
object myIEnumerableOfInt = mRef.Invoke(null, new object[]{myList});
mi = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");
mRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type);
IList myIListOfInt = (IList)mRef.Invoke(null, new object[]{myIEnumerableOfInt});
```

...but using this reflection here means you'll never be able to refer to it as `IList<int>` so the most you can infer in your code is that `myIListOfInt` is an `IList`... IMO the casting here is utterly useless.

Comment: This is exactly the structure we have, the kind to which I want to convert is captured at runtime, so I use this structure. What I want to know is if I can do this with another structure such as delegate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
var myList = list.Cast<MyType>().ToList();
```

Comment: @spender I don't see anywhere where it says the type isn't known at compile time.

Comment: @spender I don't think the OP ever said T isn't known at compile time.

Comment: Where does he say that? There's nothing wrong with this answer

Comment: itsme86 is totally right, its the perfect answer to the question, if you ignore the metaphysic information about whats going on in the background.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot to mention, these two lines are not part of the same method or class. The var t is in a class of cache and I just call it, I don't know the actual type it.

Comment: @itsme86 Sorry my mistake, I forgot to mention, these two lines are not part of the same method or class. The var t is in a class of cache and I just call it, I don't know the actual type it.

Comment: Now I'm confused.  Are you passing `T` to the other class as a generic type parameter?  e.g. `var c = new Foo<T>()`?

Comment: @David Hoerster, That's the point, I just got the `T`, I do not have `R`. In case I have only one variable of type `Type`. I only recover it. I need to convert from `T` to the type contained in `Type`.